# How can I store a user's score in a variable on my website using PHP and/or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog, radio-button

Right now I am displaying a question and its possible answers in a modal on my page (shown below). The "submit answer" button will post the form but I can't use it in my situation (I explain this at the bottom of this post) so please ignore it. [image: Modal screenshot]

I use the HTML & PHP code below to do retrieve the question and answers from my database.

```
<!-- The Modals -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- display question as heading -->
        <?php
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    echo "<h3>" . $row[ "question" ] . "</h3>";
                }
            ?>
        <button id="close1" class="close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="quiz">
                <!-- display answers as radio -->
                <div>
                <?php
                    while ($id = $choice_idResult1->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<input type= "radio" name="question1_answers" id="question1_answers_A" value= "' . $id["choice_id"] . '"';
                    }
                ?>
                    <label for="question1_answers_A">
                    <?php while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {echo $row["choice_text"];}
                            $answer1 = $row;
                    ?>
                    </label>
                </div> .....
```

When the "Open Modal 2" button is clicked, the JavaScript code below closes the modal and opens the next.

```
btn2.onclick = function() {
    checkRadio('question1_answers_B');
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}
```

As you can see, I've called a function called `checkRadio` and passes it the id of the radio input that is the correct answer.

`checkRadio` then uses an if statement to check whether that radio is checked and if it is it calls another function that increments a variable `tally`.

```
var tally = 0;

function checkRadio(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        addTally();
    }
}

function addTally() {
    tally++;
}
```

I then have a function called `showTally` that I want to display the tally in the header of the next modal (for testing purposes). However, nothing shows up in the next modal no matter what I select.

```
    function showTally() {
    document.getElementById("tally").innerHTML = tally;
}
```

And in the modal header:

```
<h3 id="tally"></h3>
```

[image: Modal 2 screenshot]

In plain English, I need to be able to identify which radio input has been selected by the user so that I can check it is the correct answer and add to the tally which will be displayed after the last question.I can't actually post the form as it will close the modal.

If you need more screenshots or information please let me know.

Comment: Id's should be unique on a page, you are creating a element in a loop using the same id each time `id="question1_answers_A"`

Comment: `$answer1 = $row;` will be set to the LAST row from the resultset processed by the previous while loop

Comment: The questions and list of answers display fine so I don't think it's a problem with me assigning those variables multiple times @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but this may help you.

```
var myAnswers1 = document.querySelector("question1_answers");
for(var i=0;i<myAnswers1.length;i++)
   {
       console.log("Question 1, radio index " + i + " is " + myAnswers1[i].checked + ".");
   }
```

Sample Output:

```
Question 1, radio index 0 is false.
Question 1, radio index 1 is true.
Question 1, radio index 2 is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, it can save info to the session, the info exists when you refresh or redirect html page (same domain).
Here is usage below:

```
var tally = localStorage.getItem('tally') || 0
function addTally() {
    tally++;
    localStorage.setItem('tally', tally)
}
```